# Covering map between orientable compact connected surfaces without boundary with genus $g$

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Similar to a previous question I asked, this is the other question that I couldn't answer in an exam I gave for my Topology course:

*Suppose $g_1,g_2$ are non-negative integers such that $2-2g_2$ divideds $2-2g_1$. I have to construct a covering map $S_{g_1} \rightarrow S_{g_2}$, where $S_g$ is denotes an orientable compact connected surface without boundary with genus $g$.*

Now, I attempted to try this problem for surfaces with smaller genera, for example a 2-torus and a 2-sphere. Clearly $2-2g$ is the Euler Characteristic of the said surface, and by classification of surfaces we have to only consider connected sum of 2-tori. So, I have $\chi(S^2)=2$, and $\chi(T^2) = 0$, here we have $2$ dividing $0$, hence I have to construct a covering map from $T^2 \rightarrow S^2$, and I have no idea how to move forward.

**Addendum:**
I have to got great answers to my question here but I had a doubt when it comes to the points being mapped, specifically in *Giulio Bresciani*'s answer. Clearly the handles of the figure is mapped to the handles in the figure above, but I'm unable to understand the mapping of the twist of the cover (above figure) to the extreme handles of the base (the figure below). Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One image solution: here $g_1-1=2$, $g_2-1=6$, $n=3$. If $g_1$ is greater, just add holes in the middle. If $n$ is greater, just go on with the snake. As pointed out by John Hughes, you clearly need $g_1$ (and hence $g_2$) to be strictly positive.

[image: genus]

Comment: This is truly illuminating!

Comment: Thanks! This is actually a very useful trick. You can also use it with wedge sums of several copies of $S^1$ to show that if $a-1$ divides $b-1$, then the free product of $b$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ injects into the free product of $a$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}$. For example, any free product $\mathbb{Z}\ast\dots\ast\mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Sorry to revisit this question after all this time. But I had a doubt when it comes to the points being mapped. Clearly the handles of the figure is mapped to the handles in the figure above, but I'm unable to understand the mapping of the twist of the cover (above figure) to the extreme handles of the base (the figure below). Any help?

Comment: Hi! A reason why the picture is complex is that you have to draw in R^3: this is the reason why I had to draw those strange twists. But the map itself is defined abstractly! To understand what is happening near one twist, just use your imagination to make one of the two handles disappear: then it is much clearer to see how the map is defined with only one handle, and no need of twists. Since the map is defined locally, you can do this for both handles one at time.

Comment: Another way to do this is to do it first for wedges of S^1 rather than for surfaces. When you have understood the situation for wedges of S^1, fatten them to get 3 varieties with boundaries, and restrict the map to the boundaries.

Answer (score 6):

This is a follow up to my comment on John Hughes' answer. The picture below shows how any surface of genus $g \geq 2$ covers the surface of genus $2$. I had to flatten it to draw it so hopefull you understand what I mean in the diagram. If not, looking at the Hatcher reference below will clarify it.

[image]

For the more general covering, i.e. $\Sigma_{mn+1} \to \Sigma_m$, you can look at Example $1.41$ on page $73$ of Hatcher. It's the same idea but you 'group' the holes together and then you have an action by $\mathbb{Z}_n$ where $n$ is the degree of the covering. Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is really helpful!

Comment: Really nice drawing. There's a 3-to-2 covering (very like Giulio's solution) that I draw as `()(|)() -> 2 @ ()( -> ()o` where the first thing indicates a 3-hole torus with the holes in a line. You cut it in half,  giving two identical pieces, which you can stack above each other by moving the right one above the left, and rotating it 180 degrees. If you take each piece and glue its ends together, you get two 2-holed tori, but if you glue them "crosswise" (top cut on one glues to bottom cut on the other, and vice versa, then you get your 3-torus, with an obvious projection to the 2-torus.

Answer (score 5):

Since the sphere has trivial $\pi_1$, the only (connected) covering space of a sphere is a sphere (which is its universal cover!).

It appears that the statement you were asked to prove is actually false.

(The torus *can* be written as a *branched* cover of the sphere, but that's not what's asked.)

Comment: I think the correct statement is that for $g_1, g_2 \neq 0,1$, if $\chi(S_g) = n\chi(S_{g’})$ then $S_g$ covers $S_{g’}$. Thus any surface besides the sphere or torus covers a genus 2 surface, and you can pictorially draw this cover and how to generalize it to the case where the Euler characteristic of one is a multiple of another.

Comment: I agree completely. I just wanted to save OP the trouble of sweating over a broken problem...

Comment: I know! OP’s question was on his test he says so I was just hinting toward what the person who assigned the question probably had in mind.

Comment: JohnHughes I think you get your answer! As @OsamaGhani says, then that's what I'm looking for, can you give me just a minor example, this pictorial presentation?

Comment: @junkquill I can't put pictures in a comment so I'll add it as answer!