# Covering sphere with handles

Tags: algebraic-topology

Recently in my topology homework I've stucked with the following problem:

*Prove that sphere with $n$ handles covers sphere with $m$ handles if and only if $m-1$ divides $n-1$*

So, basically, as I understand we need to prove that there exist a
covering map $p: S_n \rightarrow S_m$ (where $S_k$ is a sphere with $k$ handles) if and only if $(m-1)\big|(n-1)$.

Well, actually it doesn't look intuitive why do we need the condition $(m-1)|(n-1)$. Can't we just map all handles of $S_n$ to the handles of $S_m$ (maybe two ore more different handles of $S_n$ to one into $S_m$) and then map the rest of the $S_n$(basically just a sphere) to the rest of $S_n$ (also sphere) ?

(I understand I'm not rigorous here, but you definitely understood what I mean).

Any hints/ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How can you guarantee such a map is continuous, forget a covering map? The key insight is that $m-1$ is the genus of the sphere with $m$ handles. Then, you can construct the map via [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2816786/covering-map-between-orientable-compact-connected-surfaces-without-boundary-with)

Comment: Think about the case when $n=1, m=0$ or vice-versa. Can there be such a covering map?

Comment: Actually, the genus of a sphere with $m$ handles is $m$ @DonThousand. On the other hand, $m-1$ is proporational to the Euler characteristic of the sphere with $m$ handles.......

Comment: @LeeMosher Ah, it's been a while since I worked on topology, I forgot whether it was the genus which was the number of holes or $2-2g$ which is.